# How can we get the xml data in c#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to get the data from this XML document. How can I get it?

```
<GROUP NAME="Suspense A/c" RESERVEDNAME="">
   <PARENT TYPE="String">&#4; Primary</PARENT>
   <LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
      <NAME.LIST TYPE="String">
       <NAME>Suspense A/c</NAME>
      </NAME.LIST>
   </LANGUAGENAME.LIST>
</GROUP>
```

I need these values

1. Group Name (`Suspense A/c`)
2. Parent (`Primary`)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do some searching in google with key words parsing xml file in c#, you will get lots of ways

Comment: Be more specific about the `&#4;` part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a fan of the Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize method

So it would be something like

```
List<Suff> variable = new List<Stuff>();

XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(variable.GetType());

using(XmlReader reader = new XmlReader.Create("Path"))
{
   variable = (List<Stuff>)xml.Deserialize(reader);
}
```

Now of course, you'd have to have all your classes set up correctly for it to work. But that's easy enough, right?